# How to Add Overview Map on top of Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can some one please let me know if it is possible to have an overview map on top of google map?
ArcGIS API is offering this widget at [this link](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/widget_overviewmap/) so I would like to know that if we can do the same on Google Map>

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation of the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Overview](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlsOverview)

To open it by default, add this to your mapOptions:

```
    overviewMapControl: true,
    overviewMapControlOptions: {opened: true}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9jyho21/)

code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var map;
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.382971, -1.4702737),
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    overviewMapControl: true,
    overviewMapControlOptions: {
      opened: true
    }
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks geocodezip can you please also let me know how to set size of the overview map?

Comment: You can't modify the built in control's size (at least as far as I can tell from the documentation).  If you want to customize an overview map control, look at the [extoverviewcontrol](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extoverviewmapcontrol/docs/reference.html) third party library.